# Closed-form expression for h-step forecast for AR(2) process

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to derive $\mathbb E[y_{t+h} \mid y_t]$ where $y_t$ is an AR(2) process
$$
y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \phi_2y_{t-2} + c + \varepsilon_t
$$
As per usual I'm recursively applying  $\mathbb E[y_{t+h} \mid y_t] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[y_{t+h} \mid y_{t + 1}] \mid y_t]$ for $h= 2, 3, \dots$ to see if some pattern emerges, but I'm getting
$$
\mathbb E[y_{t+2} \mid y_t] = (\phi_1^2 + \phi_2)y_t + \phi_1\phi_2y_{t-1} + (\phi_1 + 1)c\\
\mathbb E[y_{t+3} \mid y_t] = (\phi_1^3 + 2 \phi_1 \phi_2)y_t + (\phi_1^2 + \phi_2^2)y_{t-1} + (\phi_1^2 + \phi_1 + \phi_2 + 1)c \\
\mathbb E[y_{t+4} \mid y_t] = (\phi^4_1 + 2\phi^2_1 \phi_2 + \phi_1^2 + \phi_2)y_t + (\phi_1^3 + 2 \phi_1 \phi_2^2)y_{t-1} + (\phi_1^3 + 2 \phi_1 \phi_2 + \phi^2_1 + \phi_1 + \phi_2 + 1)c\\
\mathbb E[y_{t+5} \mid y_t] = (\phi^5_1 + 2 \phi^3_1 + 2 \phi^3_1\phi_2 + 2 \phi_1 \phi^2_2 + \phi_1 \phi_2)y_t + \cdots 
$$
from which it's hard to see any pattern. I expected to perhaps see some binomial-expansion type pattern but I cannot see any. Searches online also yield surprisingly little results. Does anybody have a reference to such a formula if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly doubt that it's possible to obtain a formula for $\ \mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_t\big]\ $ without making some further assumptions.  Even if you assume that $\ \epsilon_t\ $ are independent normal variates with mean $\ 0\ $ and common variance $\ \sigma^2\ $ (which I will take for granted in the rest of this answer), that's still not enough to pin down a unique distribution for $\ \big(y_{t+h}\,, y_t\,\big)\ $.  If some initial values $\ (y_1,y_0)\ $, say, are assumed to be bivariate normal, and independent of $\ \epsilon_t\ $, then $\ \big(z_{t+h}\,, z_t\,\big)\ $ will be bivariate normally distributed, so you can then use the result that for such variables
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_t\,\big]=\frac{\mathbb{Cov}\big[y_{t+h}\,,y_t\big]\big(y_t-\mathbb{E}\big[y_t\big]\big)}{\mathbb{Var}\big[y_t\big]}+\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big]\ .
$$

To simplify matters, let $\ e_t=\mathbb{E}\big[y_t\big]\ $ and $\ z_t=y_t-e_t\ $. Then $\ \mathbb{E}\big[y_s\,\big|\,y_t\big]=\mathbb{E}\big[z_s\,\big|\,z_t\big]+e_s\ $,
$$
e_s=\phi_1e_{s-1}+\phi_2e_{s-2}+c\ ,
$$
and
$$
z_t=\phi_1z_{t-1}+\phi_2z_{t-2}+\epsilon_t
$$
Write this as
$$
\pmatrix{z_t\\z_{t-1}}=A\pmatrix{z_{t-1}\\z_{t-2}}+\pmatrix{\epsilon_t\\\epsilon_{t-1}}
$$
where $\ A=\pmatrix{\phi_1&\phi_2\\1&0}\ $ and $\ \epsilon_1=0\ $.  Assume (as will likely be the case) that the polynomial $\ x^2-\phi_1x-\phi_2\ $  has two distinct roots $\ \lambda_1,\lambda_2\ $ (the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $) neither of which is $1$. Then
$$
\big(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{-1}\pmatrix{1&-\lambda_2\\-1&\lambda_1}A\pmatrix{\lambda_1&\lambda_2\\1&1}=\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2}\ .
$$
Let
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{v_t\\w_t}&=\big(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{-1}\pmatrix{1&-\lambda_2\\-1&\lambda_1}\pmatrix{z_t\\z_{t-1}}\\
\pmatrix{\delta_t\\\gamma_t}&=\big(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{-1}\pmatrix{1&-\lambda_2\\-1&\lambda_1}\pmatrix{\epsilon_t\\\epsilon_{t-1}}\ .
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
v_t&=\lambda_1v_{t-1}+\delta_t\\
w_t&=\lambda_2w_{t-1}+\gamma_t\\
z_t&=\lambda_1v_t+\lambda_2w_t\ ,
\end{align}
from which we obtain
\begin{align}
v_{t+1}&=\lambda_1^tv_1+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\lambda_1^i\delta_{t+1-i}\\
w_{t+1}&=\lambda_2^tw_1+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\lambda_2^i\gamma_{t+1-i}\\
z_{t+1}&=\lambda_1v_{t+1}+\lambda_2w_{t+1}\\
&=\lambda_1^{t+1}v_1+\lambda_2^{t+1}w_1+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\big(\lambda_1^{i+1}\delta_{t+1-i}+\lambda_2^{i+1}\gamma_{t+1-i}\big)\\
&=\frac{\big(\lambda_1^{t+1}-\lambda_2^{t+1}\big)z_1+\lambda_1\lambda_2\big(\lambda_2^t-\lambda_1^t\big)z_0}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\\
&\hspace{1em}+\sum_{j=2}^{t+1}\big(\lambda_1^{t+1-j}+\lambda_2^{t+1-j}\,\big)\epsilon_j\\
&=\frac{\big(\lambda_1^{t+1}-\lambda_2^{t+1}\big)z_1+\lambda_1\lambda_2\big(\lambda_2^t-\lambda_1^t\big)z_0}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\\
&\hspace{1em}+\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\big(\lambda_1^j+\lambda_2^j\,\big)\epsilon_{t+1-j}\ .
\end{align}
Similarly, we have
$$
e_s=\frac{\big(\lambda_1^s-\lambda_2^s\big)\big(e_1-\kappa)+\lambda_1\lambda_2\big(\lambda_2^{s-1}-\lambda_1^{s-1}\big)\big(e_0-\kappa\big)}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\kappa\ ,
$$
where $\ \kappa=\frac{c}{1-\phi_1-\phi_2}\ $.

To simplify matters further, I'll now assume that $\ y_1\ $ and $\ y_0\ $ are (non-random) constants.  Then $\ z_0=z_1=0\ $, $\ z_{t+h}\,, z_t\ $ will be bivariate normally distributed with zero means, and $\ \mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,\big|\,z_t\,\big]=\frac{\mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,z_t\big]z_t}{\mathbb{E}\big[z_t^2\big]}\ $. Calculations like those given below could also be carried through under the weaker assumption that $\ (y_1,y_0)\ $ are bivariate normal, and independent of $\ \epsilon_t\ $, but the formulae will end up being even messier than those appearing below, and I couldn't be bothered trying to wade through their derivation.

From above we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,z_t\big]&=\sum_{j=2}^{t+h}\sum_{k=2}^t\big(\lambda_1^{t+h-j}+\lambda_2^{t+h-j}\ \ \big)\big(\lambda_1^{t-k}+\lambda_2^{t-k}\ \ \big)\mathbb{E}\big[\epsilon_j\epsilon_k\big]\\
&=\sigma^2\sum_{j=2}^{t+h}\sum_{k=2}^t\big(\lambda_1^{t+h-j}+\lambda_2^{t+h-j}\ \ \big)\big(\lambda_1^{t-k}+\lambda_2^{t-k}\ \ \big)\delta_{jk}\\
&=\sigma^2\sum_{j=2}^t\big(\lambda_1^{t+h-j}+\lambda_2^{t+h-j}\ \ \big)\big(\lambda_1^{t-j}+\lambda_2^{t-j}\ \ \big)\\
&=\sigma^2\Bigg(\lambda_1^h\Bigg(\frac{1-\lambda_1^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_1^2}\Bigg)+\lambda_2^h\Bigg(\frac{1-\lambda_2^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_2^2}\Bigg)\\
&\hspace{4em}+\big(\lambda_1^h+\lambda_2^h\big)\Bigg(\frac{1-\big(\lambda_1\lambda_2\big)^{t-1}}{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}\Bigg)\Bigg)\ .
\end{align}
Putting $\ h=0\ $ in this formula, we get
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[z_t^2\big]=\sigma^2\Bigg(\frac{1-\lambda_1^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_1^2}+\frac{1-\lambda_2^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_2^2}+2\Bigg(\frac{1-\big(\lambda_1\lambda_2\big)^{t-1}}{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}\Bigg)\Bigg)\ .
$$
Now setting
$$
g\big(t,h,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\big)=\lambda_1^h\Bigg(\frac{1-\lambda_1^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_1^2}\Bigg)+\lambda_2^h\Bigg(\frac{1-\lambda_2^{2t-2}}{1-\lambda_2^2}\Bigg)\\
\hspace{7em}+\big(\lambda_1^h+\lambda_2^h\big)\Bigg(\frac{1-\big(\lambda_1\lambda_2\big)^{t-1}}{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}\Bigg)\ ,
$$
we get
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,\big|\,z_t\,\big]&=\frac{g\big(t,h,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\big)z_t}{g\big(t,0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\big)}\\
\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_t\,\big]&=\frac{g\big(t,h,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\big)\big(y_t-e_t\big)}{g\big(t,0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\big)}+e_{t+h}\ .
\end{align}
If $\ \big|\lambda_1\big|<1\ $ and $\ \big|\lambda_2\big|<1\ $ then for large $\ t\ $ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,z_t\big]&\approx2\sigma^2\big(\lambda_1^h+\lambda_2^h\big)\\
\mathbb{E}\big[z_t^2\big]&\approx4\sigma_2\\
\mathbb{E}\big[z_{t+h}\,\big|\,z_t\,\big]&\approx\frac{\big(\lambda_1^h+\lambda_2^h\big)z_t}{2}\\
e_t&\approx\kappa\\
\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_t\,\big]&\approx\frac{\big(\lambda_1^h+\lambda_2^h\big)\big(y_t-\kappa\big)}{2}+\kappa\ .
\end{align}
Note that here
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_{t+1}\,\big]&\approx\frac{\big(\lambda_1^{h-1}+\lambda_2^{h-1}\big)\big(y_{t+1}-\kappa\big)}{2}+\kappa\\
\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_{t+1}\,\big]\,\big|\,y_t\big]&\approx\frac{\big(\lambda_1^{h-1}+\lambda_2^{h-1}\big)\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+1}-\kappa\,\big|\,y_t\big]}{2}+\kappa\\
&\approx\frac{\big(\lambda_1^{h-1}+\lambda_2^{h-1}\big)\big(\lambda_1+\lambda_2\big)\big(y_t-\kappa\big)}{4}+\kappa\\
&\not\approx\mathbb{E}\big[y_{t+h}\,\big|\,y_t\,\big]
\end{align}
except for some very special values of $\ h,\lambda_1\ $ and $\ \lambda_2\ $.